# List the number of employees by gender

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to achieve this output

```
SEX       Number
Male       5
Female      7
```

My code is

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX = 'M' then 1 end) as Male, COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX = 'F' then 1 end) as Female FROM EMPLOYEE
```

The output I'm getting is

```
MALE         FEMALE
5            7
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help?

Comment: SELECT COUNT (*) AS number FROM employee GROUP BY sex. Not sure of exact postgres syntax.

Comment: you are creating two column output unnecessarily .. simple group by is all you need

Answer (score 2):

Query group by gender using below

```
  SELECT
        CASE WHEN Sex ='M' THEN "Male"
             WHEN Sex ='F' THEN "Female"
        END AS Sex ,
        COUNT(*) as Number
   FROM OrderDetails 
  GROUP BY Sex;
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you need to group row's values instead of just count them.

```
SELECT SEX, COUNT(SEX) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY SEX
```